# How to know if object is of str or list or dict or int?

Tags: python

I have a list of lists and then I'm extracting the last element from the list. Now, how to know whether it's of type `str` or `list` or `dict` or `int`?

```
list2 = response_list[0][-1]
print list2,type(list2)  
print "not executing"
print list2
```

I have failed to match if that element is `list` or `str` by the following code:

```
    list2 = response_list[0][-1]
    if type(list2) == str() :
        print list2,type(list2)
    elif type(list2) == list() :
        print list2,type(list2)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Since Python 2.2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html), you should use this code:

```
if isinstance(list2, (str, list, dict)):
```

`isinstance()` takes a tuple as second argument and returns `true` if the type is in the tuple.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the type function works as

```
>>> a = []
>>> type(a)
<type 'list'>
>>> f = ()
>>> type(f)
<type 'tuple'>
```

For comparision you can use `isinstance()` function which returns `True/False`

```
    list2 = response_list[0][-1]
    if isinstance(list2,str):
        print list2,type(list2)
    elif isinstance(list2,list):
        print list2,type(list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rearrange your code like this,

```
list2 = response_list[0][-1]
if type(list2) == str:
    print list2,type(list2)
elif type(list2) == list:
    print list2,type(list2)
```

Comment: This is not recommended way to match the object type.

Comment: yes `isinstance` function is recommended. I answered this like you tried in the question. follow the accepted answers approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below using type function, pretty clean yeah?

```
dict, str, tuple, int

if type(d) is dict:
    True
```